# use recursion in this function

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, svg

I need to colour the SVG path with array data. This is the function：

```
for (var item in colorCollectionArray) {
  var village = colorCollectionArray[item].village;
  var fillColor = 'fill:'+colorCollectionArray[item].colorSet;

  $(SVG).find('path').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id)          
    if (village) {
      if (id.substring(6) === village) {
        $(this).attr('style', fillColor);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

However the efficiency is not good, it's loading slowly and I need to improve it. After googling some advice, it seems that I should use recursion. How can I do that? Is there anyone who can give some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to look through all `<path>` elements for each item in your array. since you know you are comparing the village string, you could try something like this and [select via id attribute](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
for (var item in colorCollectionArray) {
    var village = colorCollectionArray[item].village,
        fillColor = 'fill:'+colorCollectionArray[item].colorSet,
        path = $(SVG).find('path[id*="' + village + '"]');

  if (path.length) {
    path.attr('style', fillColor);
  }
}
```

without knowing what `$(SVG)` really is or without seeing your markup, i dont know if this will work out of the box.